# Running physics simulation on iOS simulator is different than on device

Tags: ios, bulletphysics, bullet

I have a basic helloworld-type routine in Bullet Physics, where each world step is hard-coded to 1/60 of second, and is therefore independent of the refresh-rate or frame-rate of the app or device. There is no interaction, just some objects falling and moving around. It works on both simulator and device, but subtle changes to how they fall, where they hit, vary between the simulator or device, even though repeated runs are always the same within an environment.

I can't understand what would be the difference between a simulator and a device for purposes of just crunching numbers. Would there be a big difference in numerical precision that could cause things like many iterations of a physics world to vary? Or some other obvious reason?

Comment: I am also facing same issue in my spritekit game in swift. I am using NSTimeInterval in update function to update the score. And have some hero which is came on screen according the score. When i play game in simulator it work slow and when i test game on Device it work faster. I can't understand the ression.